# Почему AES расшифровывается именно таким образом?

Tags: java, криптография, шифрование, aes

Использую шифрование AES с разными режимами (далее в примере режим "CBC"). Зашифровываю следующий файл с текстом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вношу ошибку в получившийся шифрованный код примерно в середине текста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При дешифровке получается следующий текст.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно вопрос: почему неправильно расшифровывается именно этот отрезок текста, ведь как я понял из документации AES (и как мне объяснял преподаватель) неправильно расшифровываться должен весь текст, содержащийся после внесенной ошибки? Как сделать, чтобы работало именно так?

Код класса (в "mode" передаю режим):

```
public class AesCipher {

    private static final String INIT_VECTOR = "ItIsOurBigSecret";

    // зашифрование
    static byte[] encrypt(byte[] secretKey, byte[] plainText, String mode) {

        try {
            if (!isKeyLengthValid(secretKey)) {
                throw new Exception("Длина ключа должна быть 128, 192 или 256 бит!");
            }

            IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(INIT_VECTOR.getBytes());
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey, "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/" + mode + "/PKCS5Padding");
            if (mode.equals("ECB"))
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
            else
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);

            return cipher.doFinal(plainText);
        } catch (Throwable cause) {
            System.out.print(cause.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }


    // дешифрование
    static byte[] decrypt(byte[] secretKey, byte[] cipherText, String mode) {

        try {
            if (!isKeyLengthValid(secretKey)) {
                throw new Exception("Длина ключа должна быть 128, 192 или 256 бит!");
            }

            IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(INIT_VECTOR.getBytes());
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey, "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/" + mode + "/PKCS5Padding");
            if (mode.equals("ECB"))
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
            else
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec);

            return cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
        } catch (Throwable cause) {
            System.out.print(cause.getMessage());
            Controller.ShowMessage(cause.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }


    // проверка длины ключа
    private static boolean isKeyLengthValid(byte[] key) {
        return key.length == 16 || key.length == 24 || key.length == 32;
    }
```

Comment: AES, по идеи, блоками шифрует, вот и только часть текста (блок) сломался

Comment: @Mike, было CBC, при других режимах то же самое. А если никакой режим не включить он все равно будет шифровать или вылетит ошибка?

Comment: @gil9red, а вот [здесь](https://habr.com/company/rambler-co/blog/279835/) написано так "Надежность шифрования обеспечивается тем, что изменение даже одного блока влечет за собой изменение последующих блоков и полное изменение конечных данных на выходе."

Comment: Не вижу где это вы используете CBC - покажите, не верю

Comment: @Barmaley, "CBC" передается в переменной mode (проверено), уж поверьте :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все правильно. AES обрабатывает данные блоками. В режиме CBC для расшифровки одного блока используется 2 блока шифротекста. Выглядит это приблизительно так:

```
расшифрованый_блок = aes_decrypt(зашифрованый_блок) xor (предыдущий_зашифр_блок)
```

По-этому ошибка в 1 байте шифротекста приведет к неправильной расшифровке только одного блока. Плюс один байт в другом блоке (из-за операции xor).

Если вам нужно, что бы ломались все блоки после ошибки, можете использовать другой режим шифрования, например PCBC обладает таким свойством.

Comment: @СергейГуков Я обновил ответ. CFB имеет такое же свойство как и CBC.

Comment: а режимы ECB и OFB аналогичные?

Comment: @СергейГуков ECB это самый простой способ, там просто блоки не зависят друг от друга. Вы так же получите ошибку в 1 блоке. OFB это потоковый шифр, Неправильный байт в шифротексте приведет к ошибке только в 1 байте в расшифрованном тексте.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что ответ верный - должны ломаться все блоки после ошибочного, а не только тот который непосредственно после ошибки... Сомневаюсь, что ТС реально использует CBC - больше похоже на ECB

Comment: @Barmaley вы не правы, возьмем хотя бы википедию: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#Propagating_Cipher_Block_Chaining_(%D0%A0%D0%A1%D0%92%D0%A1) "Режим РСВС — вариант режима СВС, обладающий специфическим свойством — ошибка шифротекста приводит к неправильному дешифрированию всех последующих блоков."